# c# hide Label on empty Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, label

I am willing to hide the label on empty Text <-- this is my Expected output(Just pointing to make sure you understand what i am willing to be solved with the help from my pro-programmers here :P), i have enabled `AutoPostBack` and an created an event `OnTextChanged` and i defined the following code in it. But it seems to not working. Any ideas?

```
protected void TextBox_signup_loginid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox_signup_loginid.Text == "")
    {
        Label_signup_loginidcheck.Visible = false;
    }
    int found = 0;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        string query = "select count(*) from Users where LoginId = '" + TextBox_signup_loginid.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        found = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (found == 1)
        {
            Label_signup_loginidcheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label_signup_loginidcheck.Text = "LoginId Already Exists";
            Label_signup_loginidcheck.Visible = true;
            hdf.Value = "false";
        }
        else
        {
            Label_signup_loginidcheck.Visible = true;
            Label_signup_loginidcheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            Label_signup_loginidcheck.Text = "LoginId Available";
            hdf.Value = "true";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have autoeventwireup=true in the page header or are you attaching the event manually? Are other events working? Also you would be MUCH better off handling this with javascript, forcing a post back on a textbox textchange is going to cause a lot of unnecessary post and page reloading leading to a bad user experience.

Comment: What's not working what's expected output ?

Comment: All the events are working properly. I am not aware of autoeventwireup, so i guess i am attaching it manually. I agree with you on unnecessary post backs, but i don't know javascript yet. I just started coding regularly/properly 2 months ago :D ^_^. Thanks though. But, treat me as a lay man.

Comment: page loads, i entered some characters, it searched and turned the label true and showed the text 'available' or 'already exists' but then 
the thing that is not working is the 'label donot hide when all the characters from textbox are erased and pressed tab key'

Comment: @Leopard hello? help? AnyonE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is still a problem or not, but as you don't posted an answer here or made a comment on your first post, i'll try to give an answer here.

I just wanted to write that it's hard to give an answer here, because we don't know what the query is returning and if the var found is true (1) or false by default but then i noticed that you are setting back the visibility of the label Label_signup_loginidcheck at any case.

```
if (found == 1)
{
    Label_signup_loginidcheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    Label_signup_loginidcheck.Text = "LoginId Already Exists";
    **Label_signup_loginidcheck.Visible = true;**
    hdf.Value = "false";
}
else
{
    **Label_signup_loginidcheck.Visible = true;**
    Label_signup_loginidcheck.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    Label_signup_loginidcheck.Text = "LoginId Available";
    hdf.Value = "true";
}
```

This means that you make the label visible again in any case and i guess that's not what you want. I guess the label get's invisible for a very short time but then you set it back again to visible = true and you may even don't notice that change.

You should probably change your conditions in the if/else branch or remove one of these stamenets in the if or else case

```
Label_signup_loginidcheck.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, yeah. I ignored this problem and moved forward. This was the part of my university's 'final year project'. The project ran good and got me a good grade, but i didn't look back at this problem and no i didn't figure out the problem of it therefore i had nothing to post as an answer otherwise i would have. So, i'll give you a Tick.:)